# Why is cross-account access for AWS safer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS has a feature called cross-account access where you can create an IAM role where you setup a trusted entity that you give a policy. That entity can then delegate access to that role to its own entities. AWS typically recommends this for a 3rd party service that is accessing an AWS account on its customers' behalf.

This avoids having to save a customer's access key credentials at a third party source but the third party source could be compromised and use the cross-account role. It's also possible to create a specific IAM user for the use case, assign it an appropriate policy, and hand out the access keys for it.

It seems like the risk is the same either way. I understand that cross-account will use STS and generate temporary credentials but this doesn't really make anything safer if the 3rd party gets compromised. The trusting entity would have to either disable the role or disable the api key.

Comment: Are you trying to understand the difference between these two options and which is safer (and why)? Or are you trying to compare these methods of cross-account access to some other method (ie: handing out root credentials)?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the difference between the two in terms of safety and why. One would be an IAM 3rd party cross-account role with some permissions and the second would be an IAM user with the same permissions and you give the credentials out for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic analogy of the difference is handing someone an access badge (which could be used by anyone) vs handing someone an access badge that requires that person's fingerprints to successfully use.

Using an IAM user to control 3rd party access involves handing over a key/secretKey - this is the simple "access badge"

Using AssumeRole to control 3rd party access uses the same information plus a security token.  To assume a role, your AWS account must be trusted by the role. The trust relationship is defined in the role's trust policy when the role is created. This is the "access badge with fingerprint validation".

(Also, for added security, the key/secretkey for AssumeRole can be temporary credentials that expire after a specific time period.)

The [AWS AssumeRole API Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) is useful, and good base to start for learning more.

Comment: How does that make it more secure from the trusting party's perspective? The trusted entity could be compromised just as easily as access keys can (regardless of a fingerprint). I've read and implemented both cross account and access key authentication but I haven't been able to make a useful argument as to why a trusting entity would want to use cross-account in a 3rd party scenario.

Comment: Anyone can use the IAM keys - they're just a key-pair. I could take them and use them later on, and I would be indistinguishable from the trusted party they were given to.  To use the AssumeRole, you must be first authenticated as the trusted entity, and in the case of temporary credentials, use them while they haven't expired. These extra security features are what make it more secure. No security is perfect (and of course accounts can be compromised, especially if one isn't careful with account keys).